# Margins got bugged (elements are buggy) when image inside div is centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images below each other. I want them to be displayed centered horizontally and vertically inside parent div. Problem is that second element won't fit to parent div.

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

and this is what I have now:

[image: What I have now]

Here is code that I am using:

HTML:

```
<div id="slika">
    <img src="images/elementi/EXTRA_SNIZENO.png" width="auto" height="15" alt="EXTRA"> 
        <br>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="r/images/ideafissa_1.png"  width="auto" height="auto" alt="papirnatirucnik.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#slika {
border: solid 2px;
display: table;
float: left;
height: 126px;
width: 111px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-wrapper {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uhks2a37/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it `position: absolute;` to take it out of the document flow. The container `#silka` needs to be set to `position: relative;` to ensure the image is positioned relative to it rather than the viewport.

```css
#slika {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 126px;
    width: 111px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.topImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slika">
    <img src="http://tommyvirtualnikatalog.com.hr/images/elementi/EXTRA_SNIZENO.png" width="auto" height="15" alt="EXTRA" class="topImage"/>
    <br>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://tommyvirtualnikatalog.com.hr/images/akcija/neprehrana/1796_muska-carapa-ideafissa_1.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="papirnatirucnik.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/k84mgLnt/